# Swipe left or right to refresh Current View using MVVMCross

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following list of item in my viewmodel. I am showing one item at a time in the View. Lets say first item which is A. But When user swipes to right or left, I want View to refresh and show the next item, for example B.

I wonder how swipe right or left achievable to iterate through the list item using mvvmcross? Even to know direction of swipe would be more than enough.

I am looking at the following url to learn `MvxGestureRecognizerBehavior` but it is broken

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Build/blob/master/MvvmCross/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/Gestures/MvxGestureRecognizerBehavior.cs

```
public RViewModel()
 {
    Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem> {
        new ListItem { Title = "A" },
        new ListItem { Title = "B" },
        new ListItem { Title = "C" },
        new ListItem { Title = "D" },
        new ListItem { Title = "E" }
    };
 }
```

**Note:** Please keep in mind, I could able to use `viewpager` but since I am loading the similar content (just TextView) in the View, I do not want to create multiple fragments to iterate through each item. Therefore, I only want to refresh that `TextView / View` with left/right swipe action.

Comment: I think you're looking for this [file]( https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Build/blob/969c892bf4ed9c82200a7fa3d609fbeba82376dc/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Views/Gestures/MvxGestureRecognizerBehavior.cs), but seems to be for IOS. As for the question I'm afraid I can't help, I'm not an expert on MvvmCross

Comment: That is iOS, I am looking for Android. Thanks Ric.Net.

Comment: Hi @casillas. I know it's an old question but I had a question that did you put animation when swiping from left to right or right to left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface `IMotionViewModel` with an method for handling the swipe. Apply it to the ViewModel

In your droid activity implement the `GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener` interface. Handle the motion event where you require and access the ViewModel there and pass the motion or arguments there.

**ViewModel**

```
public interface IMotionViewModel
{
    void OnSwipe(bool swipeRight);
}

public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel, IMotionViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
    private string _currentString = "Hello MvvmCross";
    public string CurrentString
    {
        get { return _currentString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentString, value); }
    }

    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem> {
                new ListItem { Title = "A" },
                new ListItem { Title = "B" },
                new ListItem { Title = "C" },
                new ListItem { Title = "D" },
                new ListItem { Title = "E" }
            };
    }

    public void OnSwipe(bool swipeRight)
    {
        //do list iteration here....
    }
}
```

**Droid Activity**

```
[Activity(Label = "View for FirstViewModel")]
public class FirstView : MvxActivity, Android.Views.GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
    private GestureDetector _gestureDetector;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
        _gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        var isSwipingRight = (e2.RawX - e1.RawX) > 0 ? true : false;

        var motionVm = base.ViewModel as IMotionViewModel;
        motionVm.OnSwipe(isSwipingRight);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e) { }

    public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e) { }

    public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the above example and the swiping is working perfectly. But I just want to know if it is possible to add transition when swiping from left to right or right to left?